# Get attribute of child element

Tags: jquery, attributes

If I have the following markup:

```
<p class="header hours">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sort" sortcat="hours">
        Hours&nbsp;<span class="imgholder" sortcat="hours">&nbsp;</span>
    </a>
</p>
```

How can I target the `<span>` tag within the anchor tag? There are five other similar `<p>` tag entries, each with a different value for `sortcat=`

Comment: do you want to do something with the child span when the link is clicked or... ?

Comment: @Pruitlgoe `href="javascript:void(0)"` I thought we agreed that you don't use this abomination `:)`

Comment: @Pruitlgoe Also, you might want to prefix those custom attributes with `data-`. jQuery has great support for HTML5 `data-*` attributes via its `data()` method.

Comment: @ Šime Vidas - we did? Why should you not use it?

Comment: @mkoryak It'll hold a up or down arrow graphic depending on the last sort - first click the sort is ascending, then they alternate...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
$(".sort").click(function(){
  var cat =  $(this).children("span").attr("sortcat");
  //do something with the sortcat
});
```

Comment: Excellent, this worked exactly as I needed. I was messing up the $(this).children call by writing $(this).children.attr("sortcat")...stupid specificity... : D

Comment: no problem, by the way, you never mentioned 'clicking' anything in your question, which is why you got so many answers not about clicking anything

Comment: Excellent and brilliant; This is exactly what I was expecting

Answer (score 11):

```
$("a span[sortcat]").attr('sortcat')
```

That'll give you the first element's `sortcat` value. To get all of them, do this:

```
$("a span[sortcat]").map(function(){ return $(this).attr('sortcat') })
```

See this working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BwgDW/

Comment: What if I want to get a specific one, which ever anchor tag was clicked?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.sort span')
```

Did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways you can reference the span tag, but all of them end with " .attr('sortcat'); "  I guess it depends on how specific you want to be and how flexible you need to be if there's a few other p tags with anchor tags and spans inside.

```
$('p.header a.sort span.imgholder').attr('sortcat');

/* or */

$('span.imgholder').attr('sortcat');
```

You can select elements based upon their tag name, their class name, or by the attributes inside the tags.  Refer to jQuery's documentation on selectors:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I need to get the span tag within the specific anchor clicked - I tried seeing if I could get there using $(this), it worked to some extent, I can use $(this).parent to go up the tree but had no luck going down.

Answer (score 0):

find() finds elements within a given element.

`$('a.sort').find('span');`