# search inside all attributes in all the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there's any possibility to search inside every attribute in every element. using Jquery or javascript

Like:

```
$("[*=attr]").remove();
```

Many thanks

Comment: I think the only way would be to code something that selects every element and you would have to check each attribute....

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem - why would you ever need to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to remove all elements that have any attribute containing `attr`, as that would be what your "pseudo"-code would hypothetically do?

Comment: looks weird, and can be very hard to do it

Comment: Re @RoryMcCrossan's comment: [What's the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Also not really clear what your interpretation is of that selector. Provide examples as in [mcve]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740297/get-attribute-of-child-element check out this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, after merging few ideas on the web, here's the solution:

```
               $("*").each(function() {
                    var ks=$(this);
                    $.each(this.attributes,function(i,a){
                        if (a.value== "exemple"){
                            $(ks).remove(); //or anything else
                        }
                    })
                })
```

I hope this will help people in the future, and many thanks for your contributions.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is "Is there a selector I an use for this?" the answer is "no."

If you can list the attributes, even if it's a long list, you can do it with a group of selectors, e.g.:

```
$("[data-foo*=attr], [data-bar*=attr], [data-whatever*=attr]").remove();
```

But if you literally mean any conceivable attribute name, no, you'll have to search through the elements yourself.

You *could* do that by using the selector `*` to get a (potentially massive) jQuery set with **all** elements in it, then `filter` that by looking through the [DOM `attributes` list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) of each element.

But I think if it were me, I'd use a recursive visitor instead:

```js
// Convenient utility to find if any entry in
// an array-like structure matches
var some = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.some);

// Callback for checking if an attribute matches
function attrMatch(attr) {
  return attr.value.indexOf("attr") != -1;
}

// Walk this element and its children
function walk(element) {
  var child, next;
  // Remove this one?
  if (some(element.attributes, attrMatch)) {
    // Yes
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    return;
  }
  // No, walk its children
  for (child = element.firstElementChild;
       child;
       child = next) {
    next = child.nextElementSibling;
    walk(child);
  }
}

// After a brief pause, start walking at document.body
setTimeout(function() {
  walk(document.body);
}, 800);
```

```html
<div>
  <div data-foo="blah attr blah">delete me</div>
  <div data-bar="nope">
    <span class="attr">delete me too, remember class is an attribute</span>
    <span data-whatever="blarg attr">delete me too</span>
    <span>don't remove me</span>
  </div>
  <span data-foo="no match">nor me</span>
</div>
```

That's written for clarity rather than brevity, and without jQuery as jQuery doesn't really help much with this particular task. Could easily jQuery-it-up. For instance:

```js
// Convenient utility to find if any entry in
// an array-like structure matches
var some = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.some);

// Callback for checking if an attribute matches
function attrMatch(attr) {
  return attr.value.indexOf("attr") != -1;
}

// Walk this element and its children
function walk(element) {
  // Remove this one?
  if (some(element.attributes, attrMatch)) {
    // Yes
    $(element).remove();
    return;
  }
  // No, walk its children
  $(element).children().each(function() {
    walk(this);
  });
}

// After a brief pause, start walking at document.body
setTimeout(function() {
  walk(document.body);
}, 800);
```

```html
<div>
  <div data-foo="blah attr blah">delete me</div>
  <div data-bar="nope">
    <span class="attr">delete me too, remember class is an attribute</span>
    <span data-whatever="blarg attr">delete me too</span>
    <span>don't remove me</span>
  </div>
  <span data-foo="no match">nor me</span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```